# PowerShell Send-MailMessage equivalent in Linux

Tags: linux, centos

How can I send email via our internal SMTP server from the Linux command line?

Something like:

```
sendmessage -server smtp.mycompany.net -subject "Alert aaagh!" -body "The boron control rods have melted, again!" -to alerts@acmenuclearenergy.org
```

Maybe there's a yum package I need to install? #linuxnoob

Comment: Added an example of a command line command that might be kind of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but I was looking for exactly the same thing. A drop-in replacement for `Send-MailMessage` without additional configuration. The best alternative I found is `msmtp` which is available via `yum` and `apt`.

```
echo -e "Subject: Alert aagh!\n\nThe boron control rods have melted, again" | msmtp --auth=off  --host=smtp.mycompany.net --port=25 -t alerts@acmenuclearenergy.org
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `mailx`:

```
mailx -s "test email to nate" nathan_chu@email.com
[Type your message here]
[Press CTRL-D to end the body]
```